# Align 3 elements in tabularray

Tags: tables, alignment, tabularray

So I have a table that is showing how group numbers are distributed over days and timeslots. We either group 2 or 3 groups per timeslot. It looks like this

[image]

Are there any suggestions on how to improve the appearance of the two places
where we have 3 groups in a single timeslot? Maybe something like this looks better?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\xday}[1]{
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}
}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{c},
  cell{1}{4} = {c=2}{c},
  cell{1}{6} = {c=2}{c},
  cell{1}{8} = {c=2}{c},
  cell{2-8}{2,3} = {}{c,cyan7},
  cell{2-8}{4,5} = {}{c,azure7},
  cell{2-8}{6,7} = {}{c,cyan7},
  cell{2-8}{8,9} = {}{c,azure7},
  column{1} = {purple7,r},
  row{1} = {purple7,c},
}
          &  Tirsdag & &   Onsdag & & Torsdag & & Fredag  \\
     9:15 &     9 & 32 &     4 & 20 &   35 & 26 &         \\
    10:15 &    10 & 36 & 38 44 & 27 &    5 & 33 &         \\
    11:15 & 19 22 & 43 &    13 & 28 &    6 & 34 &         \\
    13:15 &    11 & 45 &    14 & 29 &    7 & 40 &         \\
    14:15 &    23 & 47 &    15 & 37 &   18 & 41 & 39 & 24 \\
    15:15 &    31 & 50 &    17 & 46 &   21 & 49 & 16 &  8 \\
    16:15 &       &    &    25 & 12 &      &    &    &
\end{tblr}
```

Comment: the alignment is supposed to help the reader understand, but I can't guess what they are intended to mean, presumably this is a week calendar but the data, I can't guess. One possible alignment that is possibly meaningful is the alignment you use in the source with 9 aligned with the 0 in 10 rather than centred and 19 22 aligned as if it were 22, but you could write them one above the other with a bit of a squeeze so 19 and 22 were in the same column alignment or ...

Comment: I've added a bit of information about what the table is trying to convey

Comment: hm in the original and edited version you refer to having 2 or 3 entries per slot but the layout leads you (or at least , me)  to think that the final entry is always special and there are one or two entries in the first half. If that isn't the case  I'd lose the `&`  and have a list of length 2 or 3 in a single entry,

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to get your desired alignment is to do some fussy fiddling with multiples of columns. You want to have 19 - 22 - 43 to divide Tirsdag into thirds but 9 - 32 to divide it into halves. Fraction time: That means that when you have thirds each column will be ²⁄₆ and halves will be ³⁄₆ so you'll need to do something along the lines of defining

```
 cell{1}{2} = {c=6}{c},
 cell{2-3,5-8}{2,5} = {c=3}{c, cyan7},
 cell{4}{2,4,6} = {c=2}{c,cyan7},
```

and then, because of the way spans work in `tblr`, you'll have to be sure to get the correct numbers of `&`s to fill in everything correctly (you'll want one `&` for each spanned column).

Given some of the complications here, I would be tempted to use `\SetCell` over declarations in the argument to `tblr` to make it a bit easier to follow the formatting, but it's entirely up to you for what makes the most sense.

(Other notes, `booktabs` doesn't really interact with `tabularray`. If you want access to its formatting, you should instead use `\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}` to load `booktabs`. Also `utf8` is the default encoding so you don't need to load `inputenc`.